# Error "mount: mount point /mnt/boot/efi does not exist" when trying to reinstall grub

Tags: 16.04, grub2, mount, boot-repair

I had to run fsck on the main partition and this led me to not have grub anymore. So I tried to reinstall it following the instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/).
The first solution got me the error "mount: mount point /mnt/boot/efi does not exist".
I tried also with Boot Repair but it didn't show me the "Recommended repair" button.
Please help me.

Comment: When I install grub, (very often), I open Disks to confirm my target drive and partition. the partition is where /boot/grub/grub.cfg is.

Comment: Can you please explain better?

Comment: The guide you used will work for OS installed in UEFI-mode but not for OS installed in legacy-mode.

Comment: @mook765 Mine is installed in UEFI-mode.

Comment: One common mistake is you forget to create the mount point path `/mnt/boot/efi` before mounting there. So first check whether that's been done.

Answer (score 0):

### Disks Showing Mounted Partition prior to Reinstalling GRUB

[image: Disks]

Image of Disks showing drive after running `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` prior to installing GRUB by running `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`.

Commands were run from a Live Kingston Thumb Drive.

Comment: I got the following error:

Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: @Andrea Sorry my computer is BIOS boot. Follow the instructions in the link you posted, but use Disks to confirm the correct partitions are mounted as shown in the link.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand how to confirm the positions with Disks.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo fdisk -l` while running from Live USB.

Comment: code Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296 279785471 279218176 133.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  279785472 496019455 216233984 103.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  496019456 498067455   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition

Can you also tell me how I can display these things more clearly?

Comment: @Andrea I would either take a screen shot or copy from Terminal and paste in Text Editor but what you posted is fine. Try running above again from Live USB booted in UEFI mode with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` and `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`

Comment: How can I put a screenshot in a comment? I think I already booted in UEFI mode.

Comment: I think a screen shot would have to go as an edit in the question, Cut and paste would go in the question as code. what you did is fine as a comment.

Comment: Ok. The solution didn-t work because I was already booted in UEFI mode for what I can tell. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: In case I couldn't sort this out is there a way to extract data from the partition?

Comment: @Andrea: do you see the drive/partition on Disks? if so click the little triangle lower left, if it changes to a little square, it is mounted. If you install nautilus admin: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin`. you should be able right click in Files to open the partition as administrator and access the data.

Comment: I can only see three folders: boot, boot-sav and lost+found (this one i can't open). Any idea?

Comment: @Andrea It looks like you are missing the EFI folder. Try copying the /boot/grub/EFI folder from the Ubuntu ISO to the boot partition. and run grub-install again.

Comment: There is no such folder in my ISO.

Comment: When I open my 20.04 ISO I see boot, casper, dists, **EFI**, install, isolinux, etc. EFI folder contains: BOOT which contains, BOOTx64.EFI, grubx64.efi and mmx64.efi. 18.04 ISO does not have mmx64.efi

Comment: I have 16.04 and I don't have any EFI folder in the file system. Cold be a problem of my ISO?

Comment: @Andrea My Ubuntu 16.04.5 ISO has the same folders as above, EFI folder contains: BOOT which contains, BOOTx64.EFI and grubx64.efi. Perhaps best if you could download another 16.04 ISO, if that is the version the computer has.